# What happens if two tasks try to access different parts of a struct at the same time (in c)?

Tags: c, c99

Lets say I havve an array of two structs of the type mystruct_t:

```
    typedef struct {
      uint16_t member1;
      bool member2;
    } mystruct_t;
    mystruct_t my_array[2];
```

What would happen if two tasks tried to access different parts of this array at the same time? If one task tried to access my_array[0] and another task tried to access my_array[1], would this create a race condition?

What would happen if two tasks tried to access different parts of the struct at the same time? If one task tried to access my_array[0].member1 and another task tried to access my_array[0].member2, would this create a race condition?

Update: I'm using version c99.

Comment: The struct member access part is a very good question actually. It would depend a lot on the specific system and how the compiler generates the code. You can't _assume_ that it is thread-safe, but it could be, on some systems. Accessing different parts of an array is perfectly safe though. The whole concept of parallelization is based on that assumption.

Comment: What are "tasks"? Do you mean threads? And which C version? Multithreading and the corresponding memory model have only been standardized from C11 onwards.

Comment: If `member1` and `member2` are non-atomic bit-field members with no zero-length bit-fields between them, then it not safe to concurrently update those bit-field members as discussed in C 3.14/3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A race condition means the two tasks (threads) would get different behavior depending on ordering.  This only comes into play if one or both tasks are writing (opposed to just reading) to the same location (C11).  Per [section 3.14 memory location](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> NOTE 1 Two threads of execution can update and access separate memory locations without interfering with each other.

> NOTE 2 [...]
>
> EXAMPLE        A structure declared as
>
> ```
>     struct {
>             char a;
>             int b:5, c:11, :0, d:8;
>             struct { int ee:8; } e;
>     }
> ```
>
> contains four separate memory locations: The member a, and bit-fields d and e.ee are each separate
> memory locations, and can be modified concurrently without interfering with each other. The bit-fields b
> and c together constitute the fourth memory location. The bit-fields b and c cannot be concurrently
> modified, but b and a, for example, can be.

For reading (as well as writing), you may still get performance impacts due to cache coherence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though I'm using c99 with no possibility to change version, I'm sorry for not specifying the version in my question.

Comment: The c99 specification does not define the behavior.  In practice it will like work the same way, however, you would need to consulting your compiler documentation and verify the behavior to be sure.